# Sharepoint anonymous sharing link not allowed

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

we are building an integration to Exchange with MS Graph and are trying to create anonymous sharing links.

I have activated anonymous sharing in the Office365 Admin Center, as well as in the Sharepoint Admin Center in the Site Settings as well as under the Sharing tab of the site.

When we try to use the item createLink endpoint (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink) we get this response:

```
[error] => Array
   (
       [code] => notAllowed
       [message] => The feature has been disabled. Please contact your admin to get it enabled.
       [innerError] => Array
           (
               [request-id] => 15247ab9-ccef-42aa-9e2c-0b5622bab092
               [date] => 2017-03-28T14:02:39
           )

   )
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. Tried logging a support request from Office365 and got a dude on the phone who sounded half asleep and had no idea what I was talking about. Anyone here had success with this?

The goal is to use a 
Sharepoint site/team/group (there seem to be multiple synonymous terms?) as a central document repository for a small business, and sync files to it via MS Graph from a bespoke CRM we're building for that business, with the option to sending links to individual files to clients (hence anonymous sharing link) and for employees to sync files to their local PCs using the OneDrive for Business client.

Comment: Are you trying to share a file from a SP Document Library, an user's OneDrive or an Outlook Group?

Comment: A SharePoint Document Library